# How to keep all errors in a file when using a try ... catch structure in a for loop matlab

Tags: matlab, error-handling

I have not really understood all they say here : http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/try.html and all these things with MException class... 
Basically in a structure like this

```
for ii = 1:number
    try
        do stuff
    catch
    end
end
```

How could I do to keep all the errors in a file/cell/structure/...*thing*, (whatever) with, for example, the iteration *ii* that went wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would guess you could do it like this

```
Errors ={};
for ii = 1:number
    try
        %do stuff
    catch err
        Errors{end + 1, 1} = err;
        Errors{end, 2} = ii; %note that 'end' in this line will be the same row as 'end + 1' from the line just above it
    end
end
```

Now each error will be saved on a new row of Errors in the first column, and the second column will contain the iteration value (i.e. what `ii` was) that corresponded to that error.

Comment: Ahah this seems so simple... Thanks.
But I need to define `AllTheErrors` first right ?

Comment: @mwoua I'm actually not sure that you do have to offhand :/, but that's very easy for you to test. You should test it and if you do have to then edit my answer please :)

Comment: ??? The following error occurred converting from MException to double:
Error using ==> double
Conversion to double from MException is not possible.

Error in ==> ...
AllTheErrors(end + 1, 1) = err;

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working example:

```
n = 1000;
errs = cell(n, 1);
for k = 1 : n
    try
        if rand < 0.1
            % generate an error with probability 0.1
            x = inv(ones(2,1));
        end
    catch err
        errs{k} = err;
    end
end
% now write errors to the file
idx_err = find(cellfun(@(c) ~isempty(c), errs));
fid = fopen('errors.txt', 'w');
for k = 1 : length(idx_err)
    fprintf(fid, 'idx=%d %s\n', idx_err(k), errs{idx_err(k)}.message);
end
fclose(fid);
```

You can also write more detailed report of these errors, e.g. error's stack. See [MException](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mexception.html).